# DataGridColumn don't resize

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have DataGrid.
After load application column resize correct. I use binding for DataGrid width. But resize window column doesn't resize because DataGrid have fixed width.

How correctly to set width that it was possible to change the size of a window?

My code:

```
<Grid Name="gridForDataGridNames">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="240" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="dataGridForNames"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=gridForDataGridNames, Path=ActualWidth}"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeadersVisibility="None"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}">

        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="*">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding LastName}"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the DataGrid to have MinWidth instead of Width. This will cause the grid to get bigger when the window is resized larger but stay the minimum width you need when resized smaller.

```
MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=gridForDataGridNames, Path=ActualWidth}"
```